# в crontab не выполняется bash

Tags: linux, bash, debian, cron, crontab

Есть вот такой bash-скрипт для создания бекапов mysql:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/backup/sql-backup
rm site-3.sql
mv site-2.sql site-3.sql
mv site-1.sql site-2.sql
/bin/mv site-0.sql site-1.sql
mysqldump -u USER -p PASSWORD DBNAME > /var/www/html/backup/sql-backup/site-0.sql
```

Который я запускаю по crontab на Debian в определенное время:

`00 11 * * * root sh /root/mysql-backup.sh`

Скрипт создает новый файл в `/var/www/html/backup/sql-backup/site-0.sql` , но игнорирует команды `rm` и `mv`. И тоге создается файл с тем же именем, и он не рабочий. А вот при запуске скрипта из консоли всё работает нормально.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в начало файла `crontab` вот это: `# use bash to run "*.sh" scripts.
SHELL=/bin/bash`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, и как это поможет, если пользователь явно вызывает sh?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я лишь прдполагаю) Когда-то что-то такое делал, оно не работало, я ночью гуглил и копипастил всё что подвернётся и оно заработало. Я не уверен, что ситуация аналогичная, засим и пишу в коммент, а не в ответ ибо да, не уверен, что поможет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогает. Может как отладку можно сделать?

Comment: Крон посылает вывод скриптов почтой тому пользователю, от которого он их запускает. Вот и вся отладка :)

Comment: А кронтаб рутовский?

Comment: При наличии файла, *rm* будет спрашивать у пользователя подтверждения. А какой ввод у ментатов из cron? Никакого. Для этого можно написать *rm -f*.

Comment: @0andriy указал в скрипте `rm -f site-3.sql` . Ничего не изменилось...

Comment: @donRumata других пользователей пока не было создано. Просто работает crontab. Может что-то проверить?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev проверил. Баг оказывается в `/root/mysql-backup.sh: 5: cd: can't cd to /var/www/html/backup/sql-backup`  Как так то? Папка существует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, костыльно, но решился вопрос использовав проверку.

0) Обнаружил на почте ошибку: `/root/mysql-backup.sh: line 6: cd: $'../var/www/html/backup/sql-backup\r': No such file or directory` , где меня смутил в первую очередь символ `$` . Оказалось это происки редактора на винде. Конвертнул в Unix формат через `dos2unix` утилиту

1) Добавил `pwd` в начало скрипта, чтобы понять откуда запускается скрипт.

2) Добавил в `crontab` в конец строки `# > /tmp/pwd.log 2>&1` . Проверил файл `/tmp/pwd.log`. Оказалось запуск из /root, что логично, так как явно указано в `crontab` .

3) Добавил после `pwd` переход на папку вверх, чтобы проверить работает ли вообще `cd`. Работает, в логи записалось: `/` .

4) Изменил переход в папку c возвращением к корень (`..`) :

`cd ../var/www/html/backup/sql-backup`

Всё заработало. Почему не сработало просто `cd /var/www/html/backup/sql-backup` так и не понял. Ведь указан абсолютный путь с `/` в начале.

Итого:

```
#!/bin/sh
# use bash to run "*.sh" scripts.
# SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO=root
cd ../var/www/html/backup/sql-backup
rm -f site-7.sql
mv site-6.sql site-7.sql
mv site-5.sql site-6.sql
mv site-4.sql site-5.sql
mv site-3.sql site-4.sql
mv site-2.sql site-3.sql
mv site-1.sql site-2.sql
mv site-0.sql site-1.sql
mysqldump -u root db-name > /var/www/html/backup/sql-backup/site-0.sql
```

Comment: Ну, он там явно написал, что в конце указанного пути наличествует 0x0d ('\r'), поэтому он его и не нашёл. Просто не пользуйте досовские инструменты, и станет вам щасье. `vi` — всему голова! :)